# how to run(copy) django project from one system from another system?

Tags: python, django

i was working on a project on django using one of my system(win8) now i have changed my system.how do i continue working from where i left off on my new system(win7).i have a copy of the old django project file directory and nothing else,i have installed python and django on my new system and just copying that file directory  and running `python manage.py runserver` on new system doesnt work(i wasnt hoping that it would work anyway) so what should i do?i am new in django and python so if anyone can explain me in detail.if my question arise any confusion please leave a comment.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" entail? errors? Chances are you need to install dependencies

Comment: i have some modules installed previously like ckeditor,tinymce and other things previously on my previous system should i install them on my new system as well?well anyway i did install all modules on my new system as well. .but now when i make migrations and runserver it says no module name django.db.models.loading?i dont remember using anything like that previousely

Comment: Well what version of django were you using and what version are you using now? Essentially, your question is too broad, something is different between machines and you need to figure out what that is

Comment: i guess i was using the same versions on both systems.thanks for the help.so all i needed to know was basically to run your django project on other system you just need to copy the project folder,make migrations and runserver or are there some other routine task that i should do that i am missing?

Comment: You might want to investigate [requirements files](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html). Briefly the idea is that you store all of your requirements (e.g. Django==1.8.7) in a text file `requirements.txt`. Then, when you set up the new system, you do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and you end up with the same libraries installed on the new system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django.db.models.loading` was removed in Django 1.9. You need install the same version of Django on the old and new systems.

Django is pretty good about backwards compatibility, but you can't upgrade from one version to the next and assume that everything is going to work. You need to read through the release notes first (e.g [1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/)), and make any required code changes.

Comment: so it was as you said,my previous django version was 1.8 and new one is 1.9.i msy sound dumb but how do i uninstall this version and install the older one?or how do i uninstall this version of django from my system?

Comment: If you used pip to install Django, then you can switch to 1.8.X with `pip install django==1.8.7` (1.8.7 is currently the latest release of 1.8). If you installed Django another way, I'm not sure what the best way to reinstall is, because I don't have experience running Django on Windows.